# RIFA PME271M547 replacement

Tags: capacitor, repair, vintage, replacement

I just broke my sewing machine (it's an old Viktoria machine about 30-40 years old) and now I am looking for a replacement safety capacitor. The one installed is a **RIFA PME 271 M 547** paper capacitor.

I have looked online and found a replacement on ebay 
[RIFA KONDENSATOR 275V~ SH 47n X2 PME271M 40/100/56/C](https://www.ebay.de/itm/RIFA-KONDENSATOR-275V-SH-47n-X2-PME271M-40-100-56-C/161954356286) or this one [EVOX RIFA - PME271M547M - CAPACITOR, CLASS X2, 0.047UF](https://www.ebay.de/itm/EVOX-RIFA-PME271M547M-CAPACITOR-CLASS-X2-0-047UF/181228536527).

My problem is, that the old Capacitor has a different number sequence.

[image: Old Capacitor]

It's a bit hard to see but it reads 40/065/56 while all capacitors I found had 40/100/56. I tried to find out the meaning of this values but could not find an answer.

Questions:

- Is it ok to buy the capacitors I found?
- What do these numbers mean?

Any answer is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I would not be replacing a failed RIFA cap with an Ebay example of the same part of unknown age.

These old parts are notorious for failing in a cloud of foul smelling smoke, generally 30+ years after being made, basically the housing cracks, moisture gets in and it all goes sideways.

The original is a 47nF 250V Class X2 cap.

Farnell have R463F247050N0K for less then your ebay part, that is coming from a proper distributor and will be of recent manufacture.

Basically the important things for a cap in this role are that it be class X2, and rated for at least 250V, capacitance is not that critical.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any benefit in buying the pme271m547. They are 3 times as expensive, but since I have to pay $6 for shipping to Germany I would not mind spending a bit more, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘new’ Evox Rifa are made by Kemet, but kept the Rifa brand name. Just because a eBay listing says Evox Rifa, don’t presume they are old stock. Rifa is a EU high quality made capacitor. They are pricey because of their quality. These capacitors can last well over 40 years.

Answer (score 0):

Search for PME271M547 by Farnell or other supplier.

Ref: RIFA GPC PME271M547 0.047 µF fo=7.0 MHz 250V

It is quite easy to find.

If used for interference suppression could (verify before!) be replaced by  0.047 µF / 100 Ω 600V~